# How to start developing the head unit which support Android Auto?

Tags: android-auto

We are interested in developing a head unit compatible with both CarPlay and Android Auto. For CarPlay, we have located the necessary development portal on Apple's website at https://mfi.apple.com/, which provides comprehensive guidance on getting started.

However, we are encountering challenges in finding equivalent resources for Android Auto. The available information on Google’s site primarily addresses app development for Android Auto, without detailing the integration process for head units. Does anyone have insights on the appropriate program to enroll in or a contact at Google for developing a head unit that supports Android Auto? Any guidance or points of contact would be greatly appreciated.